# BTService not updating a Blackboard Key

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I am trying to create a system for AI enemies in my game so that they "retreat" when they are low on health. In order to accomplish this, I created a BTService that actively gets the Health of a character and saves it in a Blackboard Key.

Unfortunately, I have noticed that the service is able to set the "Health" value correctly once, but doesn't appear to update it ever again. As such, the Blackboard Key constantly remains at a certain value even if the enemies' health decreases.

What essentially happens is:

> 1. There is a ShooterCharacter class with a Health variable.
> 2. In its Behavior Tree, there is a Blackboard Key also called "Health" that will store the value of Health in the ShooterCharacter class.
> 3. To achieve this, a BTService was made called "Update Character Health."
> 4. At the start of the game, Update Character Health works as intended. In the Behavior Tree, the Health key value is shown to be 70, the Health ShooterCharacter classes start off with.
> 5. However, it stops working afterward. The key remains at 70 even if the health of the ShooterCharacter class it belongs to has its health reduced to 40.

Here is the code for the Update Character Health BTService.

**BTService_CharacterHealth.h**

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.

#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "BehaviorTree/Services/BTService_BlackboardBase.h"
#include "BTService_CharacterHealth.generated.h"

/**
 * s
 */
UCLASS()
class SIMPLESHOOTER_API UBTService_CharacterHealth : public UBTService_BlackboardBase
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    UBTService_CharacterHealth();

protected: 
    virtual void TickNode(UBehaviorTreeComponent& OwnerComp, uint8* NodeMemory, float DeltaSeconds) override;   
};
```

**BTService_CharacterHealth.cpp**

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "BTService_CharacterHealth.h"
#include "AIController.h"
#include "BehaviorTree/BlackboardComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "ShooterCharacter.h"

UBTService_CharacterHealth::UBTService_CharacterHealth()
{
    NodeName = "Update Character Health";
}

void UBTService_CharacterHealth::TickNode(UBehaviorTreeComponent& OwnerComp, uint8* NodeMemory, float DeltaSeconds)
{
    Super::TickNode(OwnerComp, NodeMemory, DeltaSeconds);

    AShooterCharacter*  Character = Cast<AShooterCharacter>(OwnerComp.GetAIOwner()->GetPawn());

    if (Character == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    OwnerComp.GetBlackboardComponent()->SetValueAsFloat(GetSelectedBlackboardKey(), Character->Health);
};
```

An odd thing I noticed is that the issue with this might have something to deal with the  `OwnerComp.GetBlackboardComponent()->SetValueAsFloat(GetSelectedBlackboardKey(), Character->Health);`

I inserted the following ULOG after the `AShooterCharacter*  Character = Cast<AShooterCharacter>(OwnerComp.GetAIOwner()->GetPawn());` command.

```
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Character Health: %f"), Character->Health);
```

Oddly enough, this ULOG is able to keep up. If the Character's Health is at 40, it prints out 40. Despite this, the Blackboard Key remains at 70 even with this ULOG active.

I understand if this is somewhat loaded/confusing, I am also kind of stumped by this problem so feel free to ask me anything else.

Comment: What does `GetSelectedBlackboardKey()` do?

Comment: @john I forgot to mention that the BTService here is based on BTService_BlackboardBase. This means that the service can be assigned a Blackboard Key in the editor. GetSelectedBlackboardKey gets the blackboard key I assigned in the editor and in the command, I am setting its value to Character->Health.

Comment: I know nothing about Unreal but have you checked that method is always returning the same key? If it is not that's an obvious explanation for what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I managed to find the solution to my problem. As it turns out, the BTService does actually update accordingly. The problem was that I did an amateur hour move by not selecting a specific enemy character in the editor before checking the Behavior Tree.

The Behavior Tree apparently shows the values for the first AI character in an alphabetical list. The reason why it didn't appear to be updating is that it was showing a different character who wasn't being damaged.

Basically, when I was testing, I was shooting "ShooterCharacter_4" to see if the Health will go down. However, the behavior tree was showing the values of "ShooterCharacter_1", which was not being damaged and was at max health. As such, I mistakenly thought the Health wasn't being updated when it was.

I found that selecting the ShooterCharacter_4 in-game and going to the Behavior Tree afterward reported the Health to be 40/70 after damaging it.

I was also able to finally get this "Retreat" script going. It had nothing to do with C++, I just had to make sure that the Behavior Tree actions were aborted properly when conditionals were not met.